# Return results for current date with any time

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time, crystal-reports

I have a simple query that means to count all OId's from a table for the current day.  I want to put it in to Crystal Reports so users can generate a report daily that counts all results for the day they run it.

The code as i first figured would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(oid) from TABLE_A where DATE = CURDATE()
```

But CURDATE() only returns results with 00:00:00 time stamp.  So i get all results with **2015-08-06 00:00:00** as the date.

How do i get all results for the day regardless of time stamp?

Thanks in advance!

Mickey!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your query in a [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) way as

```
SELECT COUNT(oid) 
from TABLE_A 
where DATE >= concat(CURDATE(),' 00:00:00')
and  DATE <= concat(CURDATE(),' 23:59:59')
```

Comment: Cheers!  This works beautifully!  Cant rate it as dont have enough rep myself yet.  But thanks again!

Comment: @MikeDWakelyn but you can mark this answer as accepted read here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: Done!  Can also rep it now!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
For Current Date & Time
$CurrentDateTime=date("d-m-Y h:i:s");

=> 06-08-2015 15:33:21

For Current Date 
$CurrentDate=date("d-m-Y");

=> 06-08-2015
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing! Answers on Stack Overflow are expected to provide some context explaining what their code does and why it works. It can also be helpful to show why the asker’s code wasn’t working.